# TFS Source Control Explorer showing only local projects as not checked in

Tags: tfs

My TFS Source Control explorer has suddenly switched from showing me all the projects available in TFS (including branches etc.), to just showing me those projects in my local workspace as yet to be added:

[image: TFS Issue]

I've tried disconnecting from TFS, and searched around for any options I might have accidentally clicked but cannot find anything. Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you see those projects in pending changes?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, those projects should still be on the server. But you can double check it( Such as, check whether the team project still under “Connect to Team Foundation Server ” dialog)

Make sure you are using the same workspace and the same connected user as ever. 
[image]  [image]

Since the status is related to the workspace,there is a workaround for this situation:

1. Delete your local workspace (Check in the changes first)
2. Create a new one and remapping it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it turned out that my profile had been deleted from TFS entirely. I'm still waiting to find out how this happened.

Comment: Did you mean tfs automatically delete your profile? Only for you or also happen to others. It seems impossible. On the server,1). Check the event logs in the Event Viewer to see whether there is any useful information. 2). Also have a check on logs in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs folder.